# How to connect to my US network overseas via VPN?

Tags: vpn, netflix

I purchased an Apple TV for my parents and I have a netflix account.  My parents live overseas, and I was wondering if they could use my account to get it to work.  I read that it won't work unless you use proxies or a VPN, so I was wondering if its possible for me to setup a VPN to my network in the US instead of paying a service like StrongVPN?

Setup:

- Router in US - Airport Extreme
- Router abroad - D-link (not sure of
  model)

I know that the AppleTV doesn't have a built-in VPN client, maybe eventually when its jailbroken there will be an app, but as of now I'll have to use the routers right?

Any other ideas are welcome as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would grab a miniITX board with intel atom processor ~120$ with ram and old psu, then put some linux system on it which will run a simple VPN client, then setup a VPN server, maybe OpenVPN, in the US and tunnel their connection through yours.

**But,** I have the feeling that the vpn/tunneling of the connection will really drag down the performance, especially to overseas. Also your connection needs one massive upload capability to cope with streaming that much media over the net.

I currently have a similar setup like that for streaming media to my parents in Germany and some friends on the west coast, from the Boston area.

Comment: sounds good, but whats the reasoning for having a dedicated machine instead of using my own?

Comment: firstly its less likely to crash and be affected by whats going on on your machine, and miniITX boards can run at less than 25W, therefor energy savings

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the updated solution to this problem is as follows, which does not require the use of VPN tunnels and only proxies enough traffic to get around geo-locking (does not proxy video delivery):

1. Get a Linux VPS in the country where Netflix is available (e.g. Digital Ocean VPS)
2. Install an configure BIND DNS and SNI Proxy (HTTP/HTTPS) on the VPS
3. Set Apple TV to use the DNS server running on the VPS

[DIY clone of Netflix Tunlr/Unblock-Us/UnoTelly on cheap US based VPS](http://blog.belodedenko.me/2014/02/diy-clone-of-netflix-tunlr-vps.html)

-- ab1